# Google App Engine URL Handling

Tags: google-app-engine, url

I have a Java Google App Engine application with one module and one HTML page.

I would like to serve different content to the user, using GWT, by using different URLs.

For example:

"http://myapp.appspot.com/"  Serves the main HTML page and calls the entry point method.  This works fine.

I would like to serve different UI content when I use a browse to a URL like "http://myapp.appspot.com/differentcontent/".

I know I can set up a servlet in WEB.XML and create a server side class for that URL pattern, but how do I get back to a GWT client side class from the servlet class when the servlet call did not originate from GWT?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the History ([docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/History.html)) but your url instead of being `http://myapp.appspot.com/differentcontent/` will be `http://myapp.appspot.com/#differentcontent`.

Also take a look to this:

- http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=232
- http://www.ongwt.com/post/2008/01/20/GWT-History-Support-Tutorial